# dynatree find all selected highest level nodes

Tags: jquery, dynatree

I am trying to find all the selected highest level nodes
For example
if I have tree like
-grandparent1
  --parent1
   ---child1
   ---child2
  --parent2
   ---child3
   ---child4
If some one selects **child1,child2,child3**
I need result like **parent1,child3**
Please help me out on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the key path upto root parent using below:

```
node.getKeyPath()
```